# Hiding Tabhost with listview scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using **Fragment tab ViewPager** in my application. In every page of my `ViewPager`, I have a `Fragment` which contains a `ListView`. Now what I want to do is to hide/unhide `Tab`s on `ListView` Scroll depending upon direction of scroll. So is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you checked out the `ListView` API docs?

Comment: @Sufian what should i check? ListView and Fragment tab ViewPager are two different things.

Comment: Your question consists of 2 parts. 1) "hide/unhide `Tab`s". 2) "depending upon direction of scroll". Are you asking about both issues?

Comment: No I know how to find direction of scroll. All I want to do is to hide tab s while scrolling down and unhide while scrolling up.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by Fragment tab Viewpager? If it's a library, please update the post with the link.

Comment: If you want to remove a `Fragment` from a `ViewPager` then use `removeView()`.

Comment: No it is not a library. It is a normal TabHost whose TabContent is a ViewPager and in each page of my ViewPager, there is a Fragment.

Comment: You most likely are looking for [CoordinatorLayout using the ViewPager's RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540632/coordinatorlayout-using-the-viewpagers-recyclerview). Support library has made this "stick tabs to the top" easier after you scroll. This works with `RecyclerView` only. If you want to have this with `ListView`, you will probably need to look for libraries and I guess there are some.