# Hide toolbar on scroll design support library

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to hide toolbar on scroll in recyclerview, which is located in fragment in viewpager, if using new design support library?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    ... >
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                ...
                android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ... />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        ... />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: please show code and explain what did you try so far.

Comment: sorry, i added code to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout appears to be fine. You should however also add the behaviour inside your RecyclerView (I suppose it is in a Fragment that is later added to the ViewPager):

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and most importantly and as stated by [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30553940/959437), don't forget to update your build tools to 22 and your gradle references to at least v 22.20 of both the component and the Design Support Library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Check out [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/) for a complete tutorial.

Comment: It will also work if you will use RecyclerView to below of AppBarLayout for example
`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ..> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ..> 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" /> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recycler_view" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

Answer (score -1):

There is a control already built into the library called [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html).  It is already designed to collapse on scroll, and will include Paralax, text, and fading effects (so you should use it).