# CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and ToolBar - Toolbar doesn't scroll off the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to make my ToolBar scroll off the screen, when I scroll up my ViewPager(ViewPager is inside a fragment that is placed in FrameLayout) and show the ToolBar when I scroll down. **I am trying to achieve this using the Support Design Library.**

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.xx.xxx.DetailActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But, **the toolbar doesn't respond to scroll**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You should have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/your_scrollable_view" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="registrarNuevoUsuario"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_check"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="detail_backdrop_height">256dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: I think this approach is when you have an extended ToolBar, but all i need is to scroll the normal toolbar off the screen.

Comment: @Vamsi Chalia Then remove the part of the XML you don't need. AKA ImageView

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the toolbar to enter/exit `AppBarLayout` is sufficient. You do not need a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Try changing your `FrameLayout` into a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: I have a fragment that i am adding in the FrameLayout. So, i cannot take that out. and is there a problem with my current approach?

Comment: why aren't you using the `<fragment>` tag then? can you post the code of what you are adding? The issue is that the CoordinatorLayout can only co-operate with `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: TheonK, i think your answer should be a comment to Joaquin's answer.

Comment: I think @TheoK has a point here. For me it didn't work with a ScrollView but worked correctly with a NestedScrollView. So I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work with a FrameLayout...

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue was reported on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201822

But after release of Android Support Library, revision [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This bug is solved.**

**Fixed : AppBarLayout not scrolling out completely when used with fitsSystemWindow**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1` OR to further.

Comment: Thank you! I was using 23.2.0 version of support library and it fixed the problem. Saved my hours!

Comment: glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have inside your ViewPager? A ListView or a RecyclerView? Either way you might want to consider adding the behaviour to that scrolling element.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and most importantly and as stated by [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30553940/959437), don't forget to update your build tools to 22 and your gradle references to at least v 22.20 of both the component and the Design Support Library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Check out [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/) for a complete tutorial.