# Failed to Load fragments when tabs + viewpager inside scrollview ?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

using material design tablayout +viewpager [material design tablayout](http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/) everything works perfectly but if i m trying to put parent view as ScrollView so that my whole screen can scroll once user try to  see tabs fragment content as fragment contains listview so it is getting very low height on small devices.After adding scrollview my fragments of viewpager are not being displayed ?how to overcome in this situation ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have tried with and without CoOrdinator layout none of them working

Comment: don't use ScrollView in root layout, use NestedScrollView on your fragment inside of any Layout then set height and width according to your requirement.